# "Exclude current post" Widget wordpress (PHP help)

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Hi :) I am working on my site with the **"flexible post widget"** to show the related contents or the content that I am interested in showing on the sidebar.

The widget works very well and I'm interested in continuing to use it, especially for the design and adaptability options with my site.

**The problem?** It does not include a function for **"exclude the current post"**.

I was reviewing the code (I add it to this thread) and I think I could add some lines of code for this function **(exclude the post I'm reading)**.

Unfortunately I'm new to programming and I'm lost with what and where to add it.

Could you help me?

```
<?php
/**
 * Flexible Posts Widget: Default widget template
 * 
 * @since 3.4.0
 *
 * This template was added to overcome some often-requested changes
 * to the old default template (widget.php).
 */

// Block direct requests
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    die('-1');

echo $before_widget;

if ( ! empty( $title ) )
    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

if ( $flexible_posts->have_posts() ):

function be_exclude_current_post( $args ) {
        if( is_singular() && !isset( $args['post__in'] ) )
            $args['post__not_in'] = array( get_the_ID() );
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'be_exclude_current_post' );

?>
    <ul class="dpe-flexible-posts">
    <?php while ( $flexible_posts->have_posts() ) : $flexible_posts->the_post(); global $post; ?>
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php
                    if ( $thumbnail == true ) {
                        // If the post has a feature image, show it
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail( $thumbsize );
                        // Else if the post has a mime type that starts with "image/" then show the image directly.
                        } elseif ( 'image/' == substr( $post->post_mime_type, 0, 6 ) ) {
                            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $thumbsize );
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            </a>
        </li>
<hr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul><!-- .dpe-flexible-posts -->
<?php   
endif; // End have_posts()

echo $after_widget;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme's 'functions.php' and remove it from the widget template.

```
function be_exclude_current_post( $args ) {
    if( is_singular() && !isset( $args['post__in'] ) )
        $args['post__not_in'] = array( get_the_ID() );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'dpe_fpw_args', 'be_exclude_current_post' );
```